# Open a file in google chrome with cmd without swapping to the new tab

Tags: java, google-chrome

I'm new here and I'm looking for help, I found this way to open files on google chrome with java:

```
private void abrirVideo(String archivo) {
        File arch = new File(archivo);
        String comando = "cmd.exe /c start chrome \"" + (archivo) + "\"";
        try {
            String s = arch.getParent();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando, null, new File(s));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error abriendo archivo: " + archivo + "\n" + ex);
        }
    }
```

and it does work fine, it opens the file in the same window, but the problem I have is that it automatically swaps chrome to the new tab, I've been looking for a couple days on the web and I don't see any post about this. Is there a way to open those files (like pictures, videos, etc...) in chrome, without automatically swapping to that new tab.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a java issue at all. In your java code, you just run a command
 `cmd.exe /c start chrome "fileName"` That command opens a file in chrome in the new tab. Find the command that opens the file in the current tab (if it is possible, which I am not sure) and just run that command in your java.

Comment: Mmm no, what i want is open it in a new tab, but don't automatically go to that new tab. Like when you right click on a link, and clic "open in a new tab", you stay on the same tab you are, even tho there is a new tab.

Comment: Still, my point stands. Your java code just runs a command from command line. Find the right command that does what you want (if it is possible) and then run it from java